# If $f(m_1,m_2-1)=f(m_1-1,m_2)$, does it mean that $f(m_1,m_2) $ is independent of $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, mathematical-physics, representation-theory

In this article [Theory of Complex Spectra. II](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.62.438) Giulio Racah defines $f(m_{1} m_{2} ; jm)$ by
$$
\left(m_{1} m_{2} \mid j m\right)=(-1)^{j_{1}-m_{1}} f\left(m_{1} m_{2} ; j m\right)\left[\left(j_{1}+m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}+m_{2}\right) !(j+m) !\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} /\left[\left(j_{1}-m_{1}\right) !\left(j_{2}-m_{2}\right) !(j-m) !\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
where $\left(m_{1} m_{2} \mid j m\right)$ are the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.Then, he shows that
$$
(j-m)(j+m+1) f\left(m_{1} ~~m_{2} ; j m+1\right)=f\left(m_{1}~~ m_{2}-1 ; j m\right)-f\left(m_{1}-1~~ m_{2} ; j m\right) \tag 1
$$
Now he claims that if we set $m=j$ in $\left(1\right)$, we see that $f\left(m_{1}~~ m_{2} ; j j\right)$ is independent of $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$,  so we may write
$$
f\left(m_{1}~~ m_{2} ; j j\right)=A_{j}.
$$
My question is: why is  $f\left(m_{1}~~ m_{2} ; j j\right)$  independent of $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appreciate that $f\left(m_{1}~~~ m_{2} ; j m\right)$ is a function of 3, not 4 variables, since $m_1+m_2=m$, and the second argument, whatever it is, is always the difference of the 4th minus the first, so can be eliminated. So, define
$$
g(m_1;j,m)\equiv f\left(m_{1}~~~ m_{2} ; j m\right),
$$
so, obviously, (1) implies its right hand side $g(m_1;j,m)-g(m_1-1;j,m) $ vanishes for $m\to j$,
$$
g(m_1;j,j)=g(m_1-1;j,j),
$$
That is, it is independent of the integrally-spaced $m_1$, and, hence, the superfluous $m_2$,
so that
$$
g(m_1;j,j)=A_j.
$$

Comment: I am not seeing why is obvious that $(1)$ implies $g(m_1,j,j)=g(m_1-1,j,j)$

Comment: $m_2= m-(m_1-1)\to  j-(m_1-1)$ by definition.

Comment: suppose we have the function $f(m_1,m_2)=m_1+m_2$ with $m_1+m_2=4$. Clearly we have that $f(m_1-1,m_2)=f(m_1,m_2-1)$ . Now if we define $g(m_1)=f(m_1,4-m_1)$, we have that $g(m_1-1)=f(m_1-1,4-m_1+1)=g(m_1)$. Can we proof this for an  arbitrary function

Comment: No: you are willfully misreading Racah's definitions. *f*  vanishes if $m\neq m_1+m_2$ in the arguments of his function! In your case, there is no superfluous variable: $f(m_1-1,m_2)=f(m_1,m_2-1)\to 3$, by your very definition. Your useless $g(m_1)\equiv4$, as defined, but tells you *nothing* about *f* in general!!

Comment: I will post an answer, to clarify your answer. Comment please if you disagree with it please.

Answer (score 0):

Just to  clarify the previous answer. From $(1)$ we have that $f(m_1,m_2-1,jj)=f(m_1-1,m_2,jj)$ with the condition that $m_1+m_2-1=j$ for $m=j$. Now defining $m_2'=m_2-1$ we have that
$$f(m_1,m_2')=f(m_1-1,m_2'+1)\tag 2$$
with the condition $m_1+m_2'=j$. Now we define
$g(m_1)=f(m_1,m_2')=f(m_1,j-m_1-1)$, and so we have that
$$g(m_1-1) =f(m_1-1,m_2'+1).$$
From $(2)$ we have that $g(m_1)=g(m_1-1).$

Comment: OK, I corrected the slip-ups after (2), and yes, you are saying the same thing I did. The conditioning business instead of isolating independent variables seems to be tripping you up...

Comment: What i am not understanding is how from $f(m_1,m_2-1)=f(m_1-1,m_2)$ you've got $g(m_1,j,j)=g(m_1-1,j,j)$

Comment: Sorry, your first expression pertains to your answer, but the second one to mine, and, boy!, are they different. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Form eq (1) we have $f(m_1,m_2-1,jj)=f(m_1-1,m_2,jj)=$ . I am not seeing how from 
 this you 've  got  $g(m_1,j,j)=g(m_1-1,j,j)$ . Since  you defined $g(m_1,j,j)=f(m_1,m_2,jj)$, and we do not have condition for $ f(m_1,m_2,jj)$

Comment: You $g(m_1,j,j)=f(m_1,m_2,jj)$ and so $g(m_1-1,j,j)=f(m_1-1,m_2+1,jj)$. What you are saying is that $f(m_1,m_2,jj)=f(m_1-1,m_2+1,jj)$.Why?

Comment: From the condition that lhside vanish we have that $f(m_1,m_2-1,jj)=f(m_1-1,m_2,jj)$. I am not understanding how $f(m_1,m_2-1,jj)=f(m_1-1,m_2,jj)\rightarrow g(m_1;j,j)=g(m_1-1;j,j) $

Comment: In this last comment, $m_1+m_2-1=j$, so $m_2$ is superfluous, and can be eliminated: so $f(m_1, j-m_1,j,j)=f(m_1-1,j-m_1+1,j,j)$, the exact expression when the 2nd variable, always superfluous, is dropped.

Comment: Why you have  $m_1+m_2-1=j$?The condition is   $m_1+m_2=m=j$

Comment: NO! That's what I have been emphasizing forever. The 1st and 2nd arguments of *f* ***must*** sum to the 4th, or else *f* vanishes. Check this in all equations of the question and my answer.

Comment: Ok I understand it know. $f$ is the function of the form $f(x,y,m,j)$ with the condition that $x+y=m$. So  for example $f(m_1,m_2-1,j,j)$ does not vanish only when  $m_1+m_2-1=j$. I was stuck in the condition $m_1+m_2=m$. Thank you for your help